# foreach record in a table thats not the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In mvc4 i need a foreach that will loop through all the records in a table. My html includes:

```
@model SJBusService.Models.trip
```

The records i need are from the *bus* table 
if i try

```
foreach (var item in Model.bus)
{

}
```

i get SJBusService.Models.bus does not contain a public definition for 'getEnumerator'

How can i fix this do i need to change something in my model or what?

putting an @foreach doesn't fix my problem either.

here is my bus model

```
namespace SJBusService.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class bus 
{
    public bus()
    {
        this.trips = new HashSet<trip>();
    }

    public int busId { get; set; }
    public int busNumber { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<trip> trips { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to loop through buses or loop though trips?

Comment: i need to loop though busses

Comment: can you edit your question to show your class trip.?

Answer (score 0):

Your model ref in the view looks like a typo based on your bus class.  Did you mean for @model SJBusService.Models.trip to be @model SJBusService.Models.trips?  Also, if the model passed to view is the ICollection, then the for each just needs to ref Model.

Comment: @model SJBusService.Models.trips is already being used and yes it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your models or usage are incorrect.

If your view is given a trip, you will have a single bus:

```
Model.bus

=Model.bus.busNumber // etc.
```

On the other hand, if your view is given a bus, then you will have a collection of trips:

```
Model.trips


foreach (var trip in model.trips)
{
    ...
}
```

So you need to sort out which way the one to many goes.

If this is a journey planner of some sort then I'm guessing a given trip will have many busses (for each leg of the trip) and a bus will be associated to many trips. If so, you actually need a many-to-many model in the middle, something like

```
public class leg
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int tripId { get; set; }
    public virtual trip trip { get; set; }

    public int busId { get; set; }
    public virtual bus bus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: so there is no simple way of getting records from an unrelated data table?